# Why would Bane continue to supply the police?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

After the destruction of the city in *The Dark Knight Rises*:

> 3,000 police officers are trapped underneath in the sewer system. The police are down there for 3 months, regularly receiving food and water.

Why did Bane bother to keep supplying the police?

Comment: He's not a big fan of quick deaths

Comment: @Ryan I'd say that doctor died pretty quickly in the stadium.

Comment: Doesn't blake manages to supply the policemen? If bane was responsible of supply? How come blake establish a communication channel? And how does one shoot a person supplying to people on his boss' will?

Comment: @JackBNimble 1 quick death compared to the planned 30 million slow deaths. The exception to the rule :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

During the conversation with Batman Bane explains that he wants to keep the city hopeful right up until it's destruction. He also wants it to seem like he's giving the city back to the people and not blatantly killing people...

Yes the city is in chaos, but Bane has control, I get the impression that completely killing the police force would create chaos Bane can't control.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like he wants to keep at least a patina of civilization, as demonstrated by the Scarecrow's kangaroo court.

Comment: Seeing how nobody had contact with them, though, why didn't he just lie and pretend he was feeding the police?

Answer (score 4):

He imprisoned them just as he was once imprisoned. I believe it to be nothing more than that.